# Rename microsoft-one-outlook to outlook-for-windows

Tags: support, retag-request

[microsoft-one-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-one-outlook) seems to refer to [outlook-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-for-windows), [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_for_Windows).

Comment: It seems to refer to the "new and improved" New Outlook For Windows, as opposed to the "old" Outlook for Windows which actually has features that work and are used in businesses. I suspect "One Outlook" is a failed moniker that marketing tried to get to stick because it is the "One Outlook you need (that lacks the features you actually want)". I get the impression that Microsoft are pressing ahead with their idiotic packaging of web applications as desktop applications in the name of "unified experiences" and in so doing are removing all useful or unique features.

Comment: This is quite confusing as the Wikipedia article states Outlook for Windows is also referred to as New Outlook and Outlook (new).

Comment: It seems that "one outlook" might be their project codename: https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/new-outlook-for-windows/

Comment: @LWC - Wikipedia is community generated. Based on my interpretation of the article there are numerous inaccuracies contained within it. At this time *One Outlook* and *Outlook for Windows* are two different efforts. “One Outlook” is the codename of the effort to unify Windows Mail and Outlook into a single offering. My opinion the *One Outlook* tag should just be burned and eventually deleted.

Comment: Maybe consider fixing there, preferably with sources?

Comment: @LWC - I have a massive distrust with Wikipedia as an organization. I will never become a Wikipedia editor

Answer (score 2):

For now I've removed [microsoft-one-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-one-outlook) from the three questions it was used on.

"One Outlook" appears to be a company project or initiative rather than an actual product or software tool. It has no real place as a tag.

Comment: But there's no [tag:outlook-for-windows] so these questions are now orphan.

Comment: @LWC there is [`microsoft-outlook`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook) which is a far more relevant tag and is still present on all three questions.

Comment: But it's for the Office version, not Outlook For Windows. They are 2 separate apps, are they not?

Comment: @LWC Microsoft uses "outlook for windows" interchangeably in their introduction https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627 and denote them only as "classic" or "new". Until they give it a distinct name or we distinguish it as "new" then both are technically "outlook for windows" as well as being the Microsoft product known as Outlook, hence our tag `microsoft-outlook`. None of these options are great as tags.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the original Outlook for Windows VS the preview Outlook for Windows, both of which are unrelated to Microsoft Office Outlook?